# How would I make a "wrapping paddle" feature in my Pong game?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, pong

I'm making a Pong game in Actionscript 3 and I'm pretty much done it, however I need to create a feature where if the paddle passes the top of the screen it goes back to the bottom, and if it passes through the bottom it appears at the top. How would I create something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Y axis is for up/down so use `paddle.y` to check the position...

Some logic like this :

```
if ( paddle.y <= (-paddle.height) )
{ paddle.y = ( stage.stageHeight - paddle.height ); }
```

Just an example you can test and refine. This assumes your paddle is on stage directly. If the paddle was instead added to some container (Sprite or MovieClip) then instead you use: 
`{ paddle.y = ( containerMC.height - paddle.height ); }`

If you want an effect where, for example, the top-half of your paddle is above screen then there is a half-paddle at the bottom... for that you just use two instances (copies) of the paddle Sprite.